# Convert Javascript list into list of lists

Tags: javascript, json, nested-lists

I'm not sure if I'm using the terminology correctly, but I have a JSON file coming in with a "flat" format, and I need to make it nested.

Is there any sort of pre-existing function for something like this, or an easy way to do it? I'm not sure where to start.

Below is the incoming JSON, and the desired end format. Basically I need to use particular objects in the incoming JSON to create the nested structure. (The examples aren't exact matches, but I think they illustrate what I'm asking.)

Incoming JSON:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "1",
            "Rate1": 0.2036,
            "Rate2": 15.74,
            "Group": "Q",
            "Rate3": 0.7364,
            "Rate4": 0.10534624585157225,
            "Rate5": 0.450646,
            "Rate6": 0.9136002287024891,
            "Rate7": 299.0,
            "Rate8": 0.6050670640834576,
            "Rate9": 0.975,
            "Rate10": 85.37,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2021,
            "Rate11": 0.1403,
            "Rate12": 0.6925
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "1",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "QF",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.10489076013117728,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.9693445043625344,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": 0.9985,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2021,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },

        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "4",
            "Rate1": 0.2355,
            "Rate2": 7.94,
            "Group": "R07",
            "Rate3": 0.7269,
            "Rate4": 0.223977197444187,
            "Rate5": 0.430735,
            "Rate6": 0.6824454183151086,
            "Rate7": 641.0,
            "Rate8": 0.629005059021922,
            "Rate9": 0.9622,
            "Rate10": 41.80,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2020,
            "Rate11": 0.0557,
            "Rate12": 0.8971
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "4",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R08",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.3062421968594849,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.9510367099774124,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": 1.0,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2020,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "4",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R09",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.23084953257896423,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.9849460633271168,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": 1.0,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2020,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "4",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R10",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.4241730456588087,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.9219788256234589,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": 1.0,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2020,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "1",
            "Rate1": 0.1845,
            "Rate2": 20.32,
            "Group": "QT",
            "Rate3": 0.7708,
            "Rate4": 0.07606385307062732,
            "Rate5": 0.684233,
            "Rate6": 0.7871176012210757,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": 0.699588477366255,
            "Rate9": 0.9795,
            "Rate10": 91.17,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2019,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.3976
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "1",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "QV",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": null,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": null,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2019,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "1",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R01",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.8871360440242402,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 1.0,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": 1.0,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2019,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "1",
            "Rate1": 0.3267,
            "Rate2": 11.34,
            "Group": "R02",
            "Rate3": 0.6442,
            "Rate4": 0.025745046608248837,
            "Rate5": 0.698861,
            "Rate6": 0.985290696324155,
            "Rate7": 855.0,
            "Rate8": 0.519148936170212,
            "Rate9": 0.9652,
            "Rate10": 89.03,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2019,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.6944
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "1",
            "Rate1": 0.202,
            "Rate2": 5.99,
            "Group": "R03",
            "Rate3": 0.7465,
            "Rate4": 0.1861269125446731,
            "Rate5": 0.685765,
            "Rate6": 0.9749194755185225,
            "Rate7": 186.0,
            "Rate8": 0.157608695652173,
            "Rate9": 0.9723,
            "Rate10": 76.02,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2019,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.8605
        },

        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": 0.166,
            "Rate2": 18.51,
            "Group": "QT",
            "Rate3": 0.7597,
            "Rate4": 0.5296162457273652,
            "Rate5": 0.793463,
            "Rate6": 1.0260047007484974,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": 0.450819672131147,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": 85.70,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.3465
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "QV",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": null,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": null,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R01",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.6907048200409925,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 1.0742108894738094,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": 0.3582,
            "Rate2": 10.71,
            "Group": "R02",
            "Rate3": 0.6158,
            "Rate4": 0.056875249168640646,
            "Rate5": 0.777379,
            "Rate6": 1.0000388150390025,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": 0.431893687707641,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": 168.82,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.7368
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": 0.1817,
            "Rate2": 6.46,
            "Group": "R03",
            "Rate3": 0.7968,
            "Rate4": 0.15936491686398246,
            "Rate5": 0.961159,
            "Rate6": 0.94951731669754,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": 0.082039911308203,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": 89.38,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.7857
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R04",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.08722164850653012,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.9415194329316766,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R05",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.45491704210189976,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.8651321385074416,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": 0.1977,
            "Rate2": 13.17,
            "Group": "R06",
            "Rate3": 0.737,
            "Rate4": 0.011394482811699826,
            "Rate5": 0.862888,
            "Rate6": 0.9085722724582076,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": 0.547368421052631,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": 152.16,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.7353
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": 0.2083,
            "Rate2": 8.88,
            "Group": "R07",
            "Rate3": 0.7542,
            "Rate4": 0.46734255658986146,
            "Rate5": 0.898851,
            "Rate6": 0.8774534171107008,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": 0.619318181818181,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": 142.41,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": 0.7674
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R08",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.0964242370692665,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.7098474803911896,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R09",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.037539950872489604,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.8578252418073182,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R10",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.4793615735910559,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.9950892308754818,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        },
        {
            "Fiscal_Quarter": "2",
            "Rate1": null,
            "Rate2": null,
            "Group": "R11",
            "Rate3": null,
            "Rate4": 0.44073393812093015,
            "Rate5": null,
            "Rate6": 0.6372973022238759,
            "Rate7": null,
            "Rate8": null,
            "Rate9": null,
            "Rate10": null,
            "Fiscal_Year": 2018,
            "Rate11": null,
            "Rate12": null
        }

    ]
}
```

Desired format:

```
{
    "FY": {
        "FY19": {
            "Quarter": {
                "q1": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q2": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q3": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q4": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "FY20": {
            "Quarter": {
                "q1": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q2": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q3": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q4": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "FY21": {
            "Quarter": {
                "q1": {
                    "Group": {
                        "Group1": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group2": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.5,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        },
                        "Group3": {
                            "Rate1": 91.4,
                            "Rate2": 10.2,
                            "Rate3": 97.5,
                            "Rate4": 24,
                            "Rate5": 97.5,
                            "Rate6": 14.03,
                            "Rate7": 74,
                            "Rate8": 20,
                            "Rate9": 69
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Steve, there is no pre-built feature that will produce the magic you seek. There will be a bit of parsing and modification to transform this data into the representation you seek. It will take a number of iterations using loops or functions like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [fitler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and others. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call.

*Note the use of the [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) operator. You may have to use the commented out `||` short circuit assignment for compatibility.*

```js
const result = input.data
  .reduce((a, { Fiscal_Year, Fiscal_Quarter, Group: g, ...Rates }) => {
    const fy = `FY${('' + Fiscal_Year).substring(2, 4)}`
    const q = `q${Fiscal_Quarter}`;

    a.FY[fy] ??= { Quarter: {} };  // a.FY[fy] = a.FY[fy] || { Quarter: {} };
    a.FY[fy].Quarter[q] ??= { Group: {} };  // a.FY[fy].Quarter[q] = a.FY[fy].Quarter[q] || { Group: {} };
    a.FY[fy].Quarter[q].Group[g] = { ...Rates };

    return a;
  }, { FY: {} });

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const input = { "data": [{ "Fiscal_Quarter": "1", "Rate1": 0.2036, "Rate2": 15.74, "Group": "Q", "Rate3": 0.7364, "Rate4": 0.10534624585157225, "Rate5": 0.450646, "Rate6": 0.9136002287024891, "Rate7": 299.0, "Rate8": 0.6050670640834576, "Rate9": 0.975, "Rate10": 85.37, "Fiscal_Year": 2021, "Rate11": 0.1403, "Rate12": 0.6925 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "1", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "QF", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.10489076013117728, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.9693445043625344, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": 0.9985, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2021, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "4", "Rate1": 0.2355, "Rate2": 7.94, "Group": "R07", "Rate3": 0.7269, "Rate4": 0.223977197444187, "Rate5": 0.430735, "Rate6": 0.6824454183151086, "Rate7": 641.0, "Rate8": 0.629005059021922, "Rate9": 0.9622, "Rate10": 41.80, "Fiscal_Year": 2020, "Rate11": 0.0557, "Rate12": 0.8971 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "4", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R08", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.3062421968594849, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.9510367099774124, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": 1.0, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2020, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "4", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R09", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.23084953257896423, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.9849460633271168, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": 1.0, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2020, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "4", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R10", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.4241730456588087, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.9219788256234589, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": 1.0, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2020, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "1", "Rate1": 0.1845, "Rate2": 20.32, "Group": "QT", "Rate3": 0.7708, "Rate4": 0.07606385307062732, "Rate5": 0.684233, "Rate6": 0.7871176012210757, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": 0.699588477366255, "Rate9": 0.9795, "Rate10": 91.17, "Fiscal_Year": 2019, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.3976 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "1", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "QV", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": null, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": null, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2019, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "1", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R01", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.8871360440242402, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 1.0, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": 1.0, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2019, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "1", "Rate1": 0.3267, "Rate2": 11.34, "Group": "R02", "Rate3": 0.6442, "Rate4": 0.025745046608248837, "Rate5": 0.698861, "Rate6": 0.985290696324155, "Rate7": 855.0, "Rate8": 0.519148936170212, "Rate9": 0.9652, "Rate10": 89.03, "Fiscal_Year": 2019, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.6944 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "1", "Rate1": 0.202, "Rate2": 5.99, "Group": "R03", "Rate3": 0.7465, "Rate4": 0.1861269125446731, "Rate5": 0.685765, "Rate6": 0.9749194755185225, "Rate7": 186.0, "Rate8": 0.157608695652173, "Rate9": 0.9723, "Rate10": 76.02, "Fiscal_Year": 2019, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.8605 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": 0.166, "Rate2": 18.51, "Group": "QT", "Rate3": 0.7597, "Rate4": 0.5296162457273652, "Rate5": 0.793463, "Rate6": 1.0260047007484974, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": 0.450819672131147, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": 85.70, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.3465 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "QV", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": null, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": null, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R01", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.6907048200409925, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 1.0742108894738094, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": 0.3582, "Rate2": 10.71, "Group": "R02", "Rate3": 0.6158, "Rate4": 0.056875249168640646, "Rate5": 0.777379, "Rate6": 1.0000388150390025, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": 0.431893687707641, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": 168.82, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.7368 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": 0.1817, "Rate2": 6.46, "Group": "R03", "Rate3": 0.7968, "Rate4": 0.15936491686398246, "Rate5": 0.961159, "Rate6": 0.94951731669754, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": 0.082039911308203, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": 89.38, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.7857 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R04", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.08722164850653012, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.9415194329316766, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R05", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.45491704210189976, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.8651321385074416, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": 0.1977, "Rate2": 13.17, "Group": "R06", "Rate3": 0.737, "Rate4": 0.011394482811699826, "Rate5": 0.862888, "Rate6": 0.9085722724582076, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": 0.547368421052631, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": 152.16, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.7353 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": 0.2083, "Rate2": 8.88, "Group": "R07", "Rate3": 0.7542, "Rate4": 0.46734255658986146, "Rate5": 0.898851, "Rate6": 0.8774534171107008, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": 0.619318181818181, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": 142.41, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": 0.7674 }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R08", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.0964242370692665, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.7098474803911896, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R09", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.037539950872489604, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.8578252418073182, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R10", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.4793615735910559, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.9950892308754818, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }, { "Fiscal_Quarter": "2", "Rate1": null, "Rate2": null, "Group": "R11", "Rate3": null, "Rate4": 0.44073393812093015, "Rate5": null, "Rate6": 0.6372973022238759, "Rate7": null, "Rate8": null, "Rate9": null, "Rate10": null, "Fiscal_Year": 2018, "Rate11": null, "Rate12": null }] };
</script>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I am struggling to implement it for some reason into my workflow, but It's a great answer nonetheless. Any thoughts on why I wouldn't be able to pull down specific values by using result.FY["FY21"] ?   - I generate keys:  var FYs = Object.keys(result.FY); to fill dowpdown menus dynamically. And then I generate the next set based on the selected option.  But for some reason I can't reference down to the next level.  I'm going to keep plugging away, and maybe post a new question if I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, `result.FY["FY21"]` works for me directly on the result object. It must be something else within your implementation, definitely fodder for a different question. `console.log` can be your friend here to check the shape of the data you're dealing with at any given point.

Comment: I think I found it. I initialize a "result" variable outside of my first function in order to access it in following functions. I thought that the object you were creating would be stored to it as well. But it's not. Gotta learn what const does and how to access it down the line.